# $.validator.addMethod()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dropdownlist

```
$.validator.addMethod("ddlNames", function (value) {
        if ($("#NameList.val()=="-1") 
        {
            return false;
        }
        else 
        {
            return true;
                }        

    }, "Please select a valid Name");
```

This validation is going fine. But when i change the dropdown value (valid selection ) the error message occured previously its stil displayed. Please can any one help me out?

thanks

Comment: please spend some time editing your question properly. There's some obvious typo in the code right now - please edit it to match exactly what you have (use the code `{}` button in the editor).

Comment: Post the HTML that does your DDL.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the validation programmatically when changing the drop down.
Eg. If you have: YOUR_FORM validation. Assign a variable to the validate method.
And then call that with .form() on the change event of your dropdown.

Documentation: http://jqueryvalidation.org/Validator.form/

Sample code:

```
$('#ddlNames').change(function() {
    form_validator.form();
});

var form_validator = $("#YOUR_FORM").validate({
   ignore: "",
    rules: {
        firstname: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 2
        },
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

In document.ready you need to add another line that says (replace: # < targetform> with your form):

```
$('#<targetform>').validate({
    rules : {
        names : { ddlNames: true }
}
});
```

---

Make sure you have a `class="required"` on your `<select>`

---

You should not need to clear them yourself, but there are ways...:

```
$("#NameList").removeClass("error").addClass("valid");
```

or

```
$.validator.resetForm();
```

That will make sure you start off valid each time.

Comment: where to include this line to remove the message